# Streaming HTTP connection possible with Android?

Tags: java, android, http, comet

I am working with a HTTP rest API and I need to be able to register to receive asynchronous event notifications.

The application first establishes an event channel for event
delivery by sending a POST request to the API. The event channel is established as a streaming HTTP connection. This persistent connection is created using Comet semantics.

Is it possible set up a long running HTTP connection with Java/Android?

I believe some sort of Socket is required that allows you to post data too.

**EDIT**
The application I am creating will be on a device that always has a Ethernet connection and also mains power. So power/connectivity issues are not really a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO - comet is not suitable for consumption by low power devices on 4g...

This rest api you are consuming is not ready for mobile until it upgrades with an internal proxy/gateway to reach out on PUSH protocol to IOS/Android clients that prefer event notification via another API/ protocol that is more suitable than Comet.

If you must consume the api and reach android at the same time then consider building a proxy for your Android users that will convert the Comet-calls to android push messages.

You might look at something like Parse.com because they have great Native REST and Push for the android side. ie it would not be a big deal to proxy on a Heroko/AWS node and then send native android push to your clients.

--EDIT  [android code](https://gist.github.com/rowntreerob/7de7a9761edf980347b1)

Comment: Please see my edit... unfortunately I can' change the API, and would rather not have to modify the responses and then pass to the device.

Comment: My guess is u will have better luck with HttpUrlConn than with apache http client. You may want to invest a little time reading the android source AOSP in order to actually see what it does with the header= “Transfer-Encoding: chunked”. see my edit for android code for streaming to/from google using "chunked"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you could e.g. implement such connections in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), which runs even if your application is not running. If required, you could also request permissions to prevent the device/CPU from sleeping (e.g. [WAKE_LOCk](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK)).

What kind of connection you then use (via [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or Apache HttpClient, GET, POST etc.) is up to you and your needs. However, pay special attention to this warning in the docs:

> **Caution**: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work.

If timeouts are an issue, you might need to set those to infinite values, e.g. with `setReadTimeout(0)` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29), although connections shouldn't time-out by default) or other timeout-configurations.

Also keep in mind that long running (networking) operations can **drain the battery** really fast.

Comment: I understand that a service is long running, the issue is that the connection is not kept alive.. HttpUrlConnection for example does not stay alive long enough to act as a listener for incoming responses. Also luckily battery drain is not an issue :)

Comment: That's just a matter of time-outs then? See the edit.